# Regex before capture group OR after capture group, with single capture group

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I can only have a single capture group.

This regex achieves this, but with two capture groups.

`[^a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)s[^a-zA-Z]|:([0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z]`

Example strings:

```
2013_some_text | :05 | even more text  (12345)  # Extract 05
2018 some_text_06s-more text (2343)             # Extract 06
```

How can I rewrite this regex to have a single capture group, that checks if either there is a prefixed colon `:` OR a suffixed `s`

e.g. something like

`[^a-zA-Z]:?([0-9]+)s?[^a-zA-Z]`
but one of the two (`:?`, `s?`) must be true

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible to use a single capturing group here.

What about changing the logic?

Try

```cs
^\d{4}[ _].*?[_:](\d+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/izm3ic/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ _]                     any character of: ' ', '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [_:]                     any character of: '_', ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: quoting the question - one of the two `:?` [before] or  `s?` [after] must be true - so above solution does not address the second part!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant The point is it extracts `05` and `06` as expected.

Comment: nope! the point is to follow the logic of extraction! :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant No, if the logic cannot be expressed with the tools required. The logic must be changed.

Comment: so why to answer incorrect solution then? if it is not doable  - it is just not doable :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant The solution is correct since it extracts the expected values.

Comment: in this case `select '05' union all select '06'` can also be a solution??? just because it happen to give you expected output for particular sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = '2013_some_text | :05 | even more text  (12345)'
b = '2018 some_text_06s-more text (2343)'
c = ':07s'
d = '07'

r1 = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=:(?=\d\d(?!\w)))|(?<!:)(?=\d\ds))(.{2})')
r2 = re.compile(r'(?:(?=:\d\d(?!\w))|(?<!:)(?=\d\ds))(.{3})')

a_r1 = r1.search(a).groups()
b_r1 = r1.search(b).groups()

a_r2 = r2.search(a).groups()
b_r2 = r2.search(b).groups()

#error NoneType
#c_r1 = r1.search(c).groups()
#d_r1 = r1.search(d).groups()
#c_r2 = r2.search(c).groups()
#d_r2 = r2.search(d).groups()


print('%-4s: %s\n%-4s: %s\n\n%-4s: %s\n%-4s: %s' % 
     ('a_r1', a_r1, 'b_r1', b_r1, 'a_r2', a_r2, 'b_r2', b_r2))
```

```
a_r1: ('05',)
b_r1: ('06',)

a_r2: (':05',)
b_r2: ('06s',)
[Finished in 0.4s]
```